# How do you call a python script to be used in another python script?

Tags: python

This is my folder structure:

```
\>Process_Sypht(root folder)
 \>Sypht_Scripts(subfolder)
 \>Python_Lib_Script(subfolder)
```

Scripts from `Sypht_Script` invoke scripts in `Python_Lib_Script`.

One example being called by `Sypht_Toolbox` (inside `Sypht_Scripts`) is this script: `sypht_var` (inside `Python_Lib_Script`).
Now inside the script, here's how I tried to import `sypht_var`

[image: link cause i can't attach images yet]

Unfortunately this doesn't work, how can I improve this?

Comment: Don't post images of text. Read [ask] before you post

Comment: I think you should add two empty files, both called `__init__.py`, inside the two subfolders. This will tell Python that those folders are packages to import. Then you can `import Python_Lib_Script.sypht_var`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of doing it is to have both python scripts in the same folder, then you can import it normally with no need for using sys.path

Answer (score 0):

Your question wasn't that clear on whether you want to do it from Sypht_toolbox to sypht_var so here i did this from the Syphy_Toolbox to Sypht_var so it would be the same as for other way around as well

Sypht_var.py

```
#I am just passing a single variable for testing
name="testing"
```

Syphy_Toolbox.py

```
import sys
import os

#moves a step back
os.chdir('..');

#Setting up the path before passing to sys.path.insert
something = os.path.join(os.getcwd()+'\Python_Lib_Script')

sys.path.insert(0,something)
print(sys.path[0])
from sypht_var import name
print(name)
```

instead of going with sys.path[0] try with the os model as it works best for with the operating system that you be using.

I hope this answer resolves your issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).